# Validate values of all properties in list with a duplicate for custom method

Tags: c#, linq

I need to write a method that can compare two lists to see whether there are any differences between the two, without specifying exactly what property in the two lists to compare. For instance I cannot say:

`var exceptList = list1.Where (r => r.Name !list2.Any( r2.Name == r.Name ))`

The bold part needs to be dynamic so I can re-use the method for different types of lists. I know the following example won't work, but I need something similar:

```
var r = myLeftList.Where(p => !myRighttList.Any(p2 =>
      p2.GetType().GetProperties().GetValue(myLeftList.IndexOf(p2)) ==
      p.GetType().GetProperties().GetValue(myRighttList.IndexOf(p))));
```

Comment: Why do you want to use reflection for comparing objects instead of using the `Equals` method?

Comment: There's no specific reason, it's just the method I'm currently trying. If there's an easier or better way, I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: If your list has custom object then you should simply override the `Equals` method for that type, [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/336aedhh(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: If lists have equal items in different order, then lists are different or equal?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky in my case, they are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `Except` extension method.

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com//library/vstudio/bb300779.aspx)

Being aware of that point:

> If you want to compare sequences of objects of some custom data type,
>   you have to implement the IEqualityComparer generic interface in
>   your class.

Comment: I don't know why, but except does not return the correct values. Here's my exact code :
List<cSalesPersonRMS> myLeftList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<cSalesPersonRMS>>(LeftCompareMe.ToString());

List<cSalesPersonRMS> myRighttList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<cSalesPersonRMS>>(RightCompareMe.ToString());

IEnumerable<cSalesPersonRMS> except = myLeftList.Except(myRigttList);

Comment: @user2376648 what do you mean by "not return the correct values ?", Did you look at the IEqualityComparer part ?